# How do I proceed with this integral?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, solution-verification

$$ \int (2x)\ cos(5x)\ dx$$

I put

- $u = 2x$
- $du = 2\ dx$
- $v = \frac{1}{5}sin(5x)$
- $dv = cos(5x)\ dx$

Then I try $ uv - \int vdu $

$$ 2x \times \frac{1}{5}sin(5x) - \int 2\times\frac{1}{5}sin(5x)\ dx $$

which then gives me:

$$ 2x \times \frac{1}{5}sin(5x) + 2x \times \frac{1}{25}cos(5x) $$

This doesn't seem correct to me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's almost correct but the $x$ in second term in the final answer must not be there.

Answer must be $$2x \times \frac{1}{5}sin(5x) + 2\times \frac{1}{25}cos(5x)$$
Else everything is alright!

Comment: But if you integrate 2, isn't it 2x?

Comment: @JoseBruchez In the second term you get $-\int \frac25 sin(5x). dx$ which is simply $\frac2{25}cos(5x)$

Comment: @JoseBruchez: The integral of a product is hardly ever the product of the integrals.

Comment: Oh, so I should have combined the $2$ and the $\frac{1}{5}$ prior to integrating that second term? Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: +C${}{}{}{}{}{}$